# Не загружается файл на сервер PHP

Tags: php

Эта загрузка работает стабильно на локальном сервере, но на удаленном нет.
В форме прописан enctype="multipart/form-data.

```
<?
if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0) { // Проверяем, загрузил ли пользователь файл
    $destiation_dir = "uploads/" . $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Директория для размещения файла
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $destiation_dir); // Перемещаем файл в желаемую директорию
    $file = $destiation_dir;
    require 'proc_excel.php';
} else {
    echo 'No File Uploaded'; // Оповещаем пользователя о том, что файл не был загружен
}
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
?>
```

Comment: $destiation_dir = "uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];  У вас не полный путь к файлу здесь.

Comment: Проблема с путями, думается - это обычный узкий момент локального и продакшн.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш скрипт прекрасно работает. Тест успешный.
Возможно ошибка в пути `$destiation_dir`

```
//testfile.php
<form action="testfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" >
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?
   if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0) { 
       $destiation_dir = "uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $destiation_dir);
       $file = $destiation_dir;
       echo $file;
   } else {
       echo 'No File Uploaded';
   }
?>
```

При тесте, папка `uploads` и файл `testfile.php` находились в одном каталоге.